# How to open a pdf file in browser

Tags: c#, process.start

At the end of our software installation, if the user enabled a check box and click the finish button, it will open a pdf file. It is opened through the below code,

```
Process.Start(<pdf file path>)
```

If pdf is installed in the machine, it is opening successfully. But for the machine which doesn't have pdf, it is simply showing a pop-up telling, how do you want to open the file and within seconds the pop-up disappears and finally nothing opened.

So by default planning to open the file through browser and not through pdf reader. How to achieve that? The user might have any browser (IE/Edge/Chrome/...), so how to open a pdf file through a browser instead of pdf reader?

Comment: Embed the pdf within html and open the html instead?

Comment: yeah, that should be a good option. But in our software the release notes are in pdf format. I can request the documentation team to provide a html format instead. but not sure whether they will be ok to change the process. So mean time, I will also look for option to open a pdf file through browser.

Comment: What I meant was: leave the pdf as pdf and then have a simple html with an iframe pointing to the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would probably be to use a `file://` URI. This, by default, should be handled by the default browser.

```cs
Process.Start("file://path/to/the.pdf");
```

See [File URI Scheme (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme)

Comment: I tried this. Still it opened in the pdf reader. "file://C:\\Program Files (x86)\\TestFolder\\ReleaseNotes.pdf"

Comment: @StackUser That's because the PDF reader is the default for PDF files. Is it absolutely necessary for it to be opened in a browser, and does it open a browser when the user doesn't have a PDF reader?

Comment: You need to use third party libraries if you want to skip installation of PDF reader. radpdf.com is one of them.

Comment: @NullPointDev: In a machine which doesn't have the pdf reader installed, it is displaying the pop-up "How do you want to open this file" and listing the apps. So it would be good if it always open the files with browser.

Comment: @StackUser Then would it not make sense for the user to select their default browser from the pop-up? This eliminates the need for extra code (and thus, extra processing time) trying to figure out the user's default browser.

Comment: @NullPointDev The idea is to display the release notes without any user intervention. The release notes will not open everytime. It is just one time, once the check box is enabled for first time to display the release notes, it will create a entry in registry. So for the next installation of same software, it won't pop-up. Since it is just one time, we are looking for options, to directly open the file without any user intervention. So opening the file in a browser is what I am looking for.

Comment: try to use `Process.Start("http://path/to/the.pdf");`

Comment: @Rizquuula that's not how HTTP works, and I'm fairly certainly that would not work.